# Java Card RSAPrivateCrtKey Private Exponent "d"

Tags: java, rsa, javacard

Base on http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/security/RSAPrivateCrtKey.html I could get :

1. P, the prime factor p
2. Q, the prime factor q
3. PQ = q-1 mod p
4. DP1 = d mod (p - 1)
5. DQ1 = d mod (q - 1)

by calling every getter. But, how do I get the private exponent "d"? Should I do the calculation of private exponent "d" by manual, or is there any easy way to get private exponent "d" from RSAPrivateCrtKey?
This is just for exercise anyway, so it won't do any harm.

EDIT:
I really need private exponent "d" to make a PEM file from XML. FYI, this is just an exercise, I just want to proof the truth of RSAPrivateCrtKey in Java Card is the same with RSAPrivateCrtKey in real world (as in OpenSSL, etc). Is there any other way to proof it? Or, is there any other way to make PEM file from RSAPrivateCrtKey without private exponent "d"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work (derived from Bouncy Castle's [RSAKeyPairGenerator.java](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/RSAKeyPairGenerator.java) and verified with one RSA private key):

```
public static BigInteger getPrivateExponent(byte[] publicExponentBytes, byte[] pBytes, byte[] qBytes) {
    BigInteger e = new BigInteger(1, publicExponentBytes);
    BigInteger p = new BigInteger(1, pBytes);
    BigInteger q = new BigInteger(1, qBytes);

    BigInteger pSub1 = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    BigInteger qSub1 = q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    BigInteger phi = pSub1.multiply(qSub1);
    return e.modInverse(phi);
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You won't need the private exponent since you build your key pair using javacard.security.KeyBuilder with *TYPE_RSA_CRT_PRIVATE* option. Calling *buildKey* method would then return an instance of *RSAPrivateCrtKey*, which have enough public methods to perform any computation.

If you want some details about the algorithm itself (and how can you find d, p, q, etc.), you can find numerous articles in the web, such as this one:
http://www.techscience.com/doi/10.3970/icces.2008.005.255.pdf

Comment: d is no more or less secret than p or q.

Comment: I need private exponent "d" to make a PEM file from XML. This is just for an excercise anyway, and I want to proof the truth of RSAPrivateCrtKey in Java Card is the same with RSAPrivateCrtKey in the real world (as in OpenSSL, etc).